# JS - Change "window.location" value and objects within without redirecting

Tags: javascript

For context what I am trying to achieve is for a web proxy injection script. I am trying to change the value of `window.location` and the other objects within that. I am doing this so when a script is being proxied and uses `window.location.path`, It would output `/example` instead of `/proxy/websiteurl/example`. When I try to use `Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'href', {})` it doesn't work and says I am not allowed to do this in the console. I don't really have code to give but I would really loved if someone helped me out.

Comment: Do you have any control over the other script that's using `window.location`?

Comment: No, I get the console response ` Uncaught TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "href" ` This is my code ```Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'href', {
    
     value: 'test'
     
    })
```

Comment: I wasn't asking what error you were getting when you ran *your* patching code - I'm asking if you can control anything in the *other* script that uses `window.location`. Can you alter its source code, for example?

Comment: I am currently testing in W3Schools try it editor so no other script is being involved.

Comment: But you said the purpose is to change the behavior of some other script which is using - per your example - `window.location.path`. Can you change anything about this **other** script?

Answer (score 0):

A way to change the location without redirecting is with [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Note that when a user refreshes, it does redirect to that url unless you push state with the original `pathname` after you're done using the changed location.

```js
console.log(window.location.href);

const oldLocation = window.location.pathname;
history.pushState(null, "a title", "/new-directory");

console.log(window.location.href);

// to reset
history.pushState(null, "a title 2", oldLocation);

console.log(window.location.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a set of data that needs to be security-consistent and this is one of them; usually anything having to do with domain, URL, anything that might deceive about contents' origin, you won't be able to change.

To put it more simply: due to security consideration, JS will never allow you to make a 100% transparent proxy. It's the very first thing it is supposed to not permit.

This having said, the inner content will need to have knowledge that it's being proxied in URL manipulation. If you don't own the inner part, it's very tough luck. If you do, you should parametrize its root url based on which any interaction is computed. So @CertainPerformance 's questions in the question comments are very well directed.